# Is there a way to set -UseModernBuildSystem=NO in a Fastlane fastfile?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, fastlane

When building my app using `fastlane gym` I'm getting `error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:`. When I run into this issue using Xcode I can get rid of it by setting the build system to the legacy build system. I would like to be able to set the build system using fastlane but have not found the correct way to pass it in using `xcarg`.

I've tried using this command. `fastlane gym --xcargs "UseModernBuildSystem=no"`

Which in turn runs this: `set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./PolyAcademy.xcworkspace -scheme PolyAcademy -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/mattmarshall/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-10-21/PolyAcademy\ 2019-10-21\ 16.21.58.xcarchive UseModernBuildSystem=no archive | tee /Users/mattmarshall/Library/Logs/gym/PolyAcademy-PolyAcademy.log | xcpretty`

I'd like for this not to appear and for the app to build.

````
[16:22:00]: ▸ 2019-10-21 16:22:00.145 xcodebuild[32252:315891]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 870b9074181ce2e0318a5477d3bd3536633ee1ee was NULL
[16:22:01]: ▸ ❌  error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
[16:22:01]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **```
````

Answer (score 2):

I solved adding

```
export_xcargs: {
    useModernBuildSystem: "NO"
    }
```

to my build_ios_app config in the fastfile

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this.